# install python and make in cygwin

Tags: python, windows, makefile, cygwin, installation

I have installed Cygwin Terminal in OS Windows. But I need to install also python and make in cygwin.All of these programs are needed to run petsc library.
Does Someone know how to install these components in cygwin?

Answer (score 12):

Look into cygwin native package manager, `devel` category. You should find `make` and `python` there.

Comment: `python` is actually in the `Interpreters` and `Python` categories.

Answer (score 8):

To install Python 2: run https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe or https://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe and select:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

After running into this problem myself, I was overlooking all of the relevant answers saying to check the `setup.exe` again. This was the solution to me, there are a few specific things to check.

1. Check /bin for "make.exe". If it's not there, you have not installed it correctly
2. Run the `setup.exe`. Don't be afraid, as new package installs *append* to your installation and do not over write
3. In the `setup.exe`, make sure you run the install from the *Internet* and NOT your local folder. This was where I was running into problems. Search "make" and make sure you select to Install it, do not leave this as "Default".

Comment: "Don't be afraid, as new package installs append to your installation and do not over write!" If only I knew that so much earlier. I, too, was avoiding this solution because I didn't want to uninstall my existing installation!

Answer (score 6):

@spacediver is right on. Run cygwin's `setup.exe` again and when you get to the packages screen make sure you select `make` and `python` (and any other libs/apps you may need - perhaps gcc or g++).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a command line version to install python in cygwin

wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg

install apt-cyg /bin

apt-cyg install python

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happened due to python is not well installed. So python.exe is referenced in the shell so it can't find the file because the system is different.
Please check cygwin python is well installed.