# Error when building C++ project

Tags: c++, makefile, cygwin

I tried to build a C++ project using Cygwin. I got the following error:

```
make all 
Cannot run program "make": Launching failed

Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
```

I have `C:\cygwin64\bin` in the PATH, which contains the file `makeg`. Is there meant to be some other make file, and where can I find it?

Comment: You have clearly-shown error - you have no `make` program in any of paths you have set. You should find where is it installed and add this path to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I have only makeg, makehyper, makeweights, makebearoff and makegeo files in the whole installation.

Comment: My cygwin install has no make. It's probably not in the default install and has to be added manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install make.

If you want to know how to do that see the answers to [install python and make in cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597284/install-python-and-make-in-cygwin).

Comment: I installed it and it is found now.  However I get the error  g2o/config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "g2o/config.h" now. How can I generate config.h?

Comment: That seems to be project specific. Did you create the Makefiles? Are they part of some project that you downloaded from the web?

Comment: Yes, it is this project https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o,  and I compiled and generated it using the CMake console, there were no errors and the CMakeFiles were generated. But when I import it into eclipse and try to build, I get this mentioned error. Also I am not sure how to make an executable out of it.