# how to install python for cygwin? My python's sys.platform == "win32"

Tags: python, cygwin

My python in cygwin environment is:
sys.platform == "win32"

But I want to use pexpect.spawn(...) method which is not available on win32 platform.

I can't remember clearly how Python is installed. My installation is in:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
```

Comment: Cygwin has it´s limits. Why not install a genuine 'Linux OS' ? .... Easy : Install 'VirtualBox', and then install one or more 'Linux OS´s' into VirtualBox.

Comment: That installation is NOT cygwin one. To install cygwin python use the cywin setup. (and install also python-pexpect.

Comment: Similar question: [install python and make in cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10597284)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install python and make in cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597284/install-python-and-make-in-cygwin)